# Why do I not get 404 response code for custom Next.js 404.js page?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Here's two scenarios. One works, the other does not.

I have added a `404.js` page to my `pages` directory in Next.js 12.

If I go to a URL for which there is no route defined, for example `domain.tld/non-existing-route` then I get 404 HTTP Status Code and my custom not found page would be shown.

However, if I go to a route that has parameters, for example `domain.tld/post/slug` and provide a slug that does not exist, I still get my custom 404 page, but this time with HTTP Status Code 200.

In my `post/[slug].js` page, this is my `getServerSideProps`:

```
const getServerSideProps = async (context) => {

    const { slug } = context.params || {}

    var url = `/post/data?slug=${slug}`

    const data = await apiClient(url)

    return {
        props: {
            ...data,
        }
    }
}
```

When the `slug` does not exist, our API returns 404 and this JSON:

```
{
  "type": 404,
  "message": "Not found"
}
```

Which would be handled by our `apiClient` code and this JSON would be returned to `getServerSideProps`:

```
{ 
   statusCode: 404, 
   message: 'Item does not exist' 
}
```

Then in our `/post/[slug].js` file we have this JSX:

```
import NotFound from '../../404'

const Post = ({
    post,
    seoParameters,
    statusCode,
}) => {
    return <>
       {
           statusCode === 404
             ?
                <NotFound />
             :
                <Layout />
       }
    </>
}
```

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

In the Next.js pages directory, return [notFound](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/functions/get-server-side-props#notfound) in the `getServerSideProps` function to tell Next.js it's not a valid route.

```js
export getServerSideProps = async (context) => {
  const data = await yourApiClient(`/post/data?slug=${slug}`);

  if (!data) { // make sure data is the proper key for your api
    return { notFound: true };
  }
 
  return { props: { data } };
}
```

No additional props need to be sent to the page so you can remove the status code check and only return the `Layout` on the page.

```js
const Post = (props) => {
   console.log(props);
   return <Layout />;
}

export default Post;
```